# Mysql query to join two tables using many to many relation

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables called `Notes` another table called `Tags` and third as a Join table called `NoteTagsJoin`, Join table holds two foreign keys primary Note id and Primary Tag id. I use this query to get all Notes with tagId:

```
SELECT * FROM notes INNER JOIN note_tag_join ON notes.entryId = note_tag_join.noteId WHERE note_tag_join.tagId =:tagId
```

And this query to get all Tags:

```
SELECT * FROM tags INNER JOIN note_tag_join ON tags.tagId = note_tag_join.tagId WHERE note_tag_join.noteId =:noteId
```

How can I get Note and all its tags using just Note id with one query?

Comment: joins all 3 tables and sort data by note id

Comment: Edit your question and show sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for two joins?

```
SELECT n.*, t.*
FROM notes n INNER JOIN
     note_tag_join nt
     ON n.entryId = nt.noteId INNER JOIN
     tag t
     ON t.tagId = nt.tagId
WHERE n..entryId = :noteId
```

Comment: Would this query return note and all possible tags as one response? Or rows with same note for each tag?

Comment: @kosas . . . Separate rows for each tag, which seems consistent with the question.

Comment: hmm I see, what query should I use if I want to get tags as a list?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
LEFT JOIN table_name2 ON table_name.id = table_name2.id
LEFT JOIN table_name3 ON table_name2.id = table_name3.id
WHERE table_name.id = id;
```

Change the "id" with the appropriate id's that you're using. It's important that the id's in the JOINs are coherent, else there will be no link between them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select fields of the 3 tables, do this:

```
SELECT (fields that you want to show) FROM tableA 
INNER JOIN tableB ON tableA.commonField = tableB.commonField 
INNER JOIN tableC ON tableB.commonField = tableC.commonField
```